# Android Screen Burn - Droid X - Live wallpaper

Tags: android

I am trying to figure out if this is a bug or a feature of Droid X and some wallpaper thing. Or perhaps this is some screen-burn problem.

My app is open. Then someone closes it with the home key.  Then at some point this screen will appear.  This is what the QA department reported, and I am assuming that they left the device sitting and a watery wallpaper came up. Not sure though.  If it is a wallpaper, why would it show a picture of my "closed" app in the background?  In any case, anyone know what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: This is very odd. A bug in the launcher/LiveWallpaper shouldn't really be able to cause this because it and your app will be drawing from different buffers. So a bug in the Android framework or graphic drivers on the device? I think I've seen this a couple of times before though. Do you have the device to test on? If so I'd try to replicate it. If you manage it, I'd then try to see if it happens with (a) in-built apps and (b) a few popular third-party ones. Does it persists after a reboot - in which case it probably is some form of screen-burn, if not then it's a software issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a screen shot with ddms. If its image burn on the screen then you won't see the display problem. If you do see it then its a software problem.

Comment: what is ddms??Even i am facing this on my phone